# what is the best way to structure a collection of days in a month (backbone calendar)

Tags: backbone.js, model, structure

I'm trying my first backbone project and I've stumbled into this:

I have the MODEL and VIEW of the day (with events, layout, etc). What is the best to model the MONTH to contain a collection of days (a collection or something else - not sure) and in addition to this the model month should have some extras (like: buttons - next/prev month, etc)

can I do (something) like this:

```
month = Backbone.model.extend({
    model: {
        extras: button_model,
        days:   day_collection
    }
});
```

?

Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting the concept of models and collections mixed up. Think of a model as a singular instance of something such as, in your example, a day. If we want to get a group (or collection) of days then we use a collection to store them in.

We set up the Backbone model like so:

```
DayModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
```

Then we create a Backbone collection, clearly specifying the model we want to use:

```
MonthCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DayModel
});
```

We can create a new `DayModel` with:

```
monday = new DayModel({ name: "Monday", dayOfMonth: 12 });
```

`name` within the braces is an attribute we are giving to the new `DayModel` `monday`.

These attributes can be retrieved using:

```
monday.get('dayOfMonth');
```

which would return `12`

We can now create an instance of the `MonthCollection`:

```
july = new MonthCollection();
```

To add models to the collection (days to the month) we simply use this:

```
july.add(monday);
```

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bxn4g/1/) for further reference.

---

You mention buttons being stored in your models. In my opinion it would not be best to use models to store elements such as this. Instead you would use a Backbone view which you would populate with model data and create buttons using the ID or any such uniquely identifying attributes so that the month you want will be selected.

Please read the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org) to give you a deeper understanding of Backbone.